# cygwin or linux: what is the directory location of diff?

Tags: linux, cygwin

My normal installation of diff in cygwin seems to be missing.

Would you please tell me the normal location of diff in cygwin or linux?  This is the primary diff tool, diff(1) in the man page.

Comment: Try using cygwin's setup.exe to reinstall diffutils

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux it's in `/usr/bin/diff`

Comment: Hmm can't find it in this directory in the cygwin install.  diff is going to a CM tool diff instead.   Wonder where it is in cygwin or if it got removed.

Comment: I've never used Cygwin, so I have no idea how it relates. You asked for an answer in Cygwin **or** Linux, so I gave the Linux answer.

Comment: On Linux, normal user programs are in `/usr/bin` and `/bin`.

Comment: That's also where it is on my cygwin setup

Comment: Thanks Barmar and Eric