# cywgin x86_64: where is diff?

Tags: linux, cygwin

I did a recent cygwin 64 installation.

I cannot find the regular diff tool in either /usr/bin (as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238796/cygwin-or-linux-what-is-the-directory-location-of-diff)), and when I try to reinstall Cygwin and search on diff, all I get are things like:

```
diffstat
diffutils
bsdiff
colordiff
  etc
```

No plain [diff(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) utility.

Now it turns out I have a CM tool called Serena Dimensions installed, and so when I do a:

```
 which diff
```

I get:

```
 /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Serena/Dimensions 10.1/CM/prog/diff
```

I figured I just need to reference the "unix diff" via it's complete path, easy solution ;-)   But where is it!?

Thanks. (please see last comment, thanks)

Comment: Didn't you ask essentially the same question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238796/cygwin-or-linux-what-is-the-directory-location-of-diff/32238844#32238844

Comment: I couldn't find it where you said, and it wasn't obvious to me from the running the cygwin install 64 setup (as I explained in the question).

Comment: Maybe you want to give [Babun](https://babun.github.io/) a try. It is a Cygwin wrapper project that has a lot of preconfigured stuff in it and is even easier to install than the raw Cygwin itself. I don't know if it has the diffutils preinstalled (I'm curently on a mac), but if not there is even a little package manager (called `pact`) in Babun so you could easily install it with `pact install diffutils`.

Comment: Amazing how much folks hate a simple question on this site (per down votes).   The answer is up-voted twice, but the question down-voted 3 times.  Is the question so unclear?  The guy answering got it in one quick shot.  If you agree, please up-vote the question at least to zero. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `diff` command is provided by the `diffutils` package. Install it via `setup-x86_64.exe`.

Comment: Thank you. Amazing how much folks hate a simple question on this site (per down votes).  They must have a lot of self-fear/hatred for where they see themselves not-knowing/ignorant.